# Using iterator as position in vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to write the Eratosthenes algorithm using a vector

```
1) Fill vector with integers 2 to N
2) Find the smallest integer i, print it, delete i, 2i, 3i, etc from vector
3) Repeat 2) until i is greater than square root of N
```

I'm new to vectors and sort of stuck here:

```
std::vector<int> x (n-1);

for (int i = 2; i < n+1; i++){     //fill vector with 2 to N
    x[i-2] = i;
}

float nsq = sqrt(n);

//iterate from 2 to sqrt(n):
for (std::vector<int>::iterator current = x.begin(); *current < nsq; current++){ 

    //access positions 0,2,4,6,8 etc in first iteration, 0,3,6,9 in next, etc
    for (int position = current - x.begin(); position <= x.end(); position += *current){
        //print x[position] only in first loop
        //delete x[position]              
    }
}
```

Two questions:

1) position <= x.end(); returns an error, and I can't use 'auto' since I'm not using c++11 though I'm not sure that'd do the trick. What's the best way to fix this?

2) Is there a way to print a number only once at the start of the loop? Or am I not going in the right direction with this algorithm/overcomplicating it?

Edit: Just realized I did overcomplicate it, also thanks for the answer. Is this an acceptable algorithm?

```
for (std::vector<int>::iterator current = x.begin(); *current < nsq; current++){

        for (int position = 0; position <= x.size(); position += *current){
            if(position == 0){
                std::cout << x[position] << std::endl;
            }
        //delete x[position]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Another proposal: 1º Fill one vector<bool> with true for 2-N. 2º Iterate from 2-N, if [i] is true, you can put false in all multiples (2*i,3*i,4*i... until N). 3º Done, true values in vector are primes and false values are non-primes

Comment: `current - x.begin()` will give you the index of current. `x.begin() + position` will give you an iterator to the element at index position. This only works for random-access iterators, which a vector iterator is. Probably best to pick indices or iterators and stick to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) position <= x.end(); returns an error, and I can't use 'auto' since I'm not using c++11 though I'm not sure that'd do the trick. What's the best way to fix this?

Iterators have no awareness of their position in the container they're iterating over. At the most basic level, an iterator is just a pointer that can be moved intelligently; in the case of `std::vector`, it's really just a wrapper around a pointer.

In this code, you're checking if an index is less than or equal to a pointer; you're comparing two completely different things, which doesn't make much sense.

If you want to be aware of the iterator's position in the vector, it's best to dump iterators and just use an index, instead of trying to mix the two.

> 2) Is there a way to print a number only once at the start of the loop? Or am I not going in the right direction with this algorithm/overcomplicating it?

You can check if `position` is equal to what you expect it to be on the first iteration, and print the number if it matches.

Answer (score 0):

Once you identify a number as a prime your intention is to delete all of its multiples from the vector. Ok this is possible. BUT you can't just infer that all the multiples of 5 (for example) differ by 5 positions in the vector because you've already removed the multiples of 2 and 3, some of which are also multiples of 5. Implementation wise @amchacon's suggestion above will be much easier.